# Getting the current membership user who inserted or updated in trigger SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to get the userId of aspnet_Membership user who inserted or updated a record in a table in trigger?

Existing procedure is trigger that logs the insert and update of certain tables.

What I need to know is how to get the userId of the aspnet_Membership user who inserted or updated a record in a table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you're talking about an insert/update to a *non* membership table - you're asking if there's some way to discover which user of your website caused an insert/update into any random table in your database? The answer is no - not without additional work being done in your asp.net code.

Comment: okay thanks for the information. I just want to know why it is not possible?

Comment: Because its an uncommon requirement (in my experience), and every feature starts off in an unimplemented state - all SQL Server generally knows is the account that was used to connect to it - usually an SQL Server user account or the Windows user account that the website is running under (unless you're using impersonation, in which case it will be the *windows* user account of the users accessing the site - but still not the asp.net membership users.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the explanation. Maybe i will just add another parameter in my table for the member user id. Thanks again dude.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the username by using this code

```
  MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
if (user != null)
    string name = user.UserName;
```

Comment: This code works on asp but what i want is an sql or a trigger. Is there a way to know the one who added or update a record.